# How do I add a boolean series to a python DataFrame based on another series in said DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

SO. Long time, first time.

I'm not sure if my data set is proprietary but I can simplify. I'm dealing with a DataFrame that involves states and I was given some lists that contain information about those states.

```
         Name   Value1    Value2
0     Alabama      7.4       4.4
1    Delaware      6.4       4.4
2        Ohio      2.4       2.0
3    Virginia      1.4       1.2
```

But then I'm given some lists. Lets say they're lists of states that have had horses that were mayors at one point.

```
horse_mayor_yes = ['Alabama', 'Delaware']
horse_mayor_no  = ['Ohio', 'Virginia']
```

The output I want:

```
         Name   Value1    Value2    Horse    Horseless
0     Alabama      7.4       4.4        1            0
1    Delaware      6.4       4.4        1            0
2        Ohio      2.4       2.0        0            1
3    Virginia      1.4       1.2        0            1
```

I know I could create lists of 1's and 0's, but I want something I can scale up in situations with, say, hundreds of named items if I'm given new unordered lists (assuming unique names).

Thanks!

e1: Thank you, user, for correcting my typos.
e2: The lists need not be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Why are there different `yes` and `no` lists?  Is it possible that some states can be `NaN`/aka "unsure"?

Comment: "Alabama" and "Delaware" are spelled incorrectly in your example input and output.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks for the correction! 

Yes, it's possible, but that is outside the scope of my question. I hope (and plan) to utilize the answer in outer situations with similar circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `isin()`:

```
df["Horse"] = df.Name.isin(horse_mayor_yes)
df["Horseless"] = ~df.Horse

df
       Name  Value1  Value2  Horse Horseless
0   Alabama     7.4     4.4   True     False
1  Delaware     6.4     4.4   True     False
2      Ohio     2.4     2.0  False      True
3  Virginia     1.4     1.2  False      True
```

If you need to convert `bool` to `int`, use:

```
df[["Horse", "Horseless"]] = df[["Horse", "Horseless"]].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:
It's not clear from the question that `horse` and `horseless` can both be True at same time.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Alabama','Deleware','Ohio','Virginia'],
                    'value1':[1,2,3,4], 'value2':[5,6,7,8]})


horse_mayor_yes = ['Alabama', 'Deleware']
horse_mayor_no  = ['Ohio', 'Virginia']

df['Horse'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(horse_mayor_yes), 1, 0)
df['Horseless'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(horse_mayor_no), 1, 0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
       Name  value1  value2  Horse  Horseless
0   Alabama       1       5      1          0
1  Deleware       2       6      1          0
2      Ohio       3       7      0          1
3  Virginia       4       8      0          1
```

Comment: Yes, they can be. I'll correct for that. Thank you.

Comment: In that case, my answer will work fine in your case.